# does blender care what GPU I use?

Tags: gpu

When supplies are more available, I'll be building a new PC and am wondering if Blender works better with NVidia or AMD GPUs or if it even cares. Is it more important to have a card with more RAM?

Thanks!

--ted

Comment: This is really too general for stack exchange, but typically Blender supports NVIDIA GPUs better than others; although AMD support is improving.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very general question and the answer varies over time.  You can always check the open data benchmarks to see what the current status is:  https://opendata.blender.org/

Historically, Blender has worked better with NVIDIA GPUs, but a lot of effort is being currently spent on improving AMD performance.

Yes, more RAM is better, but even that statement has exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I realize this is broad question, but one I need help with as I weigh my purchasing decisions for this app and my others. As long as there are no strong reasons one way or another, that's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: It doesn't really matter since blender works with both.

Longer Answer: Blender has better support with Nvidia GPU's rather than AMD GPU's, along with this Nvidia's Developer Program has many more Nvidia-Optimized add-ons for Nvidia GPU's using blender. Such as the Optix denoiser which allows Nvidia GPU's to have clear images even with a low render sample count, along with the Optix Render Engine (which is still in WIP). Due to the GPU shortages now, it's more just a matter of availability.

Answer (score 0):

You should get an Nvidia GPU. OpenCL kernel is losing support in 3.0, so you may not be able to use a AMD GPU for rendering in Cycles. The blender Dev team is working with AMD to get other kernels to work, but they said it would most likely not happen until after 3.0 is released. You can read more about this in the last paragraph [here](https://code.blender.org/2021/04/cycles-x/)